# Activiti equivalent function for SQL 'like' query

Tags: sql, activiti

Suppose a string execution variable 'anyVariable' is having values as multiple uniqueID's separated by space (in between and in start and end of the string).

**anyVariable**=" 123 456 5678 978 "

I want to get the count of processes where 'anyVariable' execution variable contains " 456 ".

I wrote following query : assuming **uniquId**=456

```
count = execution.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().createExecutionQuery().processVariableValueLike("anyVariable"," "+uniqueID+" ").count();
```

but its not detecting any.
I want to do something similar as like '%456%' in activiti.

Comment: Maybe I need to use processVariableValueLike("anyVariable","% "+uniqueID+" %")

Comment: why are you adding spaces? like already assumes % in the query

Comment: @AbbasKararawala If I won't add space thn it will show output even if the uniqueID is contained in another Unique ID.
for eg. In this case, if anyVariable=" 234567 ". Then searching for 456 will return  true, which should not happen! hence I am taking space on both sides into consideration. Also it does not assume '%', we need to add wildcard character just like in SQL